# Can you ping SQL Server and request to know what driver it needs to connect?

Tags: python, sql-server, api, driver

We recently ran into an issue where I have to update all of my Python tools that connect to our SQL Server. As I understand it now the `SQL Native Client 11.0` is being deprecated and replace with a different drive.

I do not want to have to update all my tools again in the future so I am trying to figure out if there is a programmatic way to check or request the correct driver information from the server directly.

Maybe it would be a library for Python that can do this or some API call that can be done against an SQL Server.

Is anyone aware of a method of checking for what driver a server might require so one can programmatically select the correct driver for connection to an SQL Server via some library such as `pyodbc`?

To be clear this is how we currently connect:

```
import pyodbc


conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', host='server_name',
                      database='dbNAME', trusted_connection='yes')
```

Comment: There is no language/platform agnostic way of doing this directly in SQL Server.  This would need to be done via an external service.

Comment: @squillman. That's too bad. I guess I will run a loop in python and just check each driver locally against the server and when I find the one that work I will save it in a json file programmatically for the next time the tool runs.

Comment: `I do not want to have to update all my tools again in the future` there's no way to do that with any service, database, product or language. 11.0 is *ancient* - it was released before 2014. Besides, if you program for Python you wouldn't be using the Native client, you'd be using the [ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), especially if you want your application to run on Windows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use `native client 11` as it was the only drive we had to connect to the SQL Server on our computers in the office. I use `pyodbc` to connect. It has all worked fine for the past 2 years. So I was thinking if there was a way to simply ping the server or call an API to check that would be cool but I could not find anything on that.

Comment: If you randomly choose a driver, you have no guarantee that your code will run correctly as driver functionality changes. In addition, The database engine has no knowledge of what drivers are installed on what machine, nor does it care. AFAIK there is no direct mechanism to know which driver supports which database engine. Your path leads to unsupportable madness.

Comment: @SMor... Well that is unfortunate. However I will likely have a solution down the road as we are working on converting all my applications to be Web Based instead of App Based so we can simply update once on the server side instead of having to create new EXE files and sent out to everyone who needs them. That process may take some time so I was hoping for a better solution in the mean time. Oh well worth a shot.

Comment: @Mike-SMT `the last two years` that driver is deprecated for a lot longer than that. The ODBC drivers are available a lot longer than that. The first SQL Server version that run on Linux and thus used exclusively ODBC came out in 2017. By then Microsoft had already announced it would shift development to ODBC exclusively. Why did you ever use that driver instead of the ODBC driver?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used the driver we were told to use. I do not run the SQL Server. I build tables and jobs in the server but I have nothing to do with its maintenance. Keep in mind in this company some severs/mainframes are super old and could not be updated due to lack of developers to update everything else that is supported by those server. Some of our stuff is really out of date.

Comment: @Mike-SMT you're running the application. The application selects the driver, not the server. What you ask *is not done by any database*. Just for security reasons this would be a really bad idea

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not sure what you are getting at. When we first requested access to the server we were informed to use native client 11 to connect. That was the end of it for us. We just used what we were told to use and it has worked fine thus far.

Comment: It would also be disastrous as far as performance is concerned. Opening a connection would be *very* slow if each time you called `Open` you had to check for a driver version. Downloading the driver would be far worse, stealing network bandwidth from other connections. Also for stability - what would happen if there were breaking changes?

Comment: @Mike-SMT `it has worked fine thus far` why did you post a question then? You were using an already deprecated and non-portable driver for two years. What changed?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because its changing and we will no longer be allowed to use native client 11. So I was looking for a programmatic way to handle this going forward just in case it happens again. Its clear from what people have said that I will not be able to do that so I will hard code the drive we were told to use `OLE DB Provider for SQL Server` and be done with it for now.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos **Opening a connection would be very slow if each time you called Open you had to check for a driver version.** As for this the goal would have been to check each driver in a list produced by `pyodbc.drivers()` and once I found one that worked I would then store that result in a json file and simply use that for everything going forward until it didn't work down the road and the program would have simply gone through the process again. So it would only have had to do that process once until conditions change in the future. I can see now that wont be good enough here.

Comment: @Mike-SMT, you mentioned "OLE DB Provider for SQL Server". That driver is even older than "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" and is included with Windows only for legacy application backwards compatibility. Nothing is futureproof but the latest OLE DB driver is [OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (MSSQLOLEDB).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When you refer to `non-portable driver` I think you are talking about the fact that a driver needs to be installed first and cannot be simply pulled to be used at the time its needed. I get that. The context in this case is that our computers are pre loaded with many drivers for different things. Or sometimes we have to request that a specific driver is installed by IT as we even as DEV's do not have access to do this.  Drivers are not something I have to worry about on the daily and have not had to do a bunch with them so I was not aware of a lot of what has been said here.

Comment: @DanGuzman Maybe I miss ready what was on the screen when I quoted "OLE DB Provider for SQL Server". It could have been "OLE DB Driver for SQL Server". The update is not meant to happen until the 1st of the year so I was just trying to get things done early. I will of coarse make sure I get the right one going forward. But thank you for the link. I will take some time to read it.

Comment: Not to add to the confusion but the latest ODBC driver is [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). That's probably what you need for pyodbc.

Comment: @DanGuzman could be however thats not up to me. We can only use what has been approved for use. They are super strict about every little thing.

Comment: @Mike-SMT, I understand. Just be aware the implication is you won't be able to use pyodbc.